# how to transform json sensitive response according to config keys in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app providing json api, and I want to transform some sensitive response body to `***` according to config keys, such as `account_no: '123***456'`

any gems or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the Rails [built-in parameter filters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/ParameterFilter.html).

Basic use:

```
[2] pry(main)> filter = ActionDispatch::Http::ParameterFilter.new(%i[account_no])
#<ActionDispatch::Http::ParameterFilter:0x00000003ce0128 @filters=[:account_no]>
[3] pry(main)> filter.filter(foo: 'bar', account_no: 'secret')
{
           :foo => "bar",
    :account_no => "[FILTERED]"
}
```

The only drawback is that you can't change the substitution value, as it's a constant that cannot be configured.

Update: if you need more customization, you might want to check out the [ParameterFilter source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameter_filter.rb). It's very straightforward and should give you a good clue to get started with your own solution.